# Toggling div visibility for a graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a flow graph using HTML, CSS and JS. 
This is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Newtt/HRedA/3/

This is my JS:

```
var flag = false;
function showdiv(id) {
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    div.style.display = flag ? 'none' : 'block';
    flag = !flag;
}
```

It shows the root node of the graph and has to be clicked on to increase the levels.

As you can see there are some issues regarding the number of clicks required to show the divs that are hidden. I would like some help to fix two things:

1. Number of clicks required
2. When I open stage two and stage three, clicking on stage one should collapse all the open stages. However, with the current code, that doesnt seems to be working.

Comment: Flag is "global" and thus shared amongst all clicks (using the flag as the stat of what was last clicked, not the last click on that element)

Comment: It might be easier to use the `data-*` attribute on the div elements than checking a global var.

Comment: Yeah, I realised flag is global. But does that mean that I'll have to set a separate variable for toggling visibility of each stage of the graph?

Comment: @Robb, is it possible for you to show me what you mean?

Comment: Or you can use the display value of the div itself as the flag.

Comment: @ChrisB Using display as a "flag" is a good idea...

Comment: I saved a working example here as well: http://jsfiddle.net/HRedA/17/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting the display-flag on the actual element you will avoid toggling a global state:

```
function showdiv(id) {
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    var divFlag = div.expandedFlag == true
    div.style.display = divFlag ? 'none' : 'block';
    div.expandedFlag = !divFlag;
}
```

Or even simpler by using the elements display-state to decide if show/hide:

```
function showdiv(id) {
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    div.style.display = (div.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
}
```

**Including Part 2:**
For part two. Including a structure containing children nodes for recursive hiding:

```
function showdiv(id) {
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    var hideFlag = (div.style.display == 'block');
    div.style.display = (hideFlag ? 'none' : 'block');
    if(hideFlag){hideChildren(id)}
}

var children = {
    'two' : ['three-one','three-two']
};

function hideChildren(parent) {
    if(children[parent] !== undefined){
        for(var i = 0; i<children[parent].length; i++){
            var id = children[parent][i]
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
            hideChildren(id)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, both answers fix problem one perfectly for me. Thanks! Now onto the second issue.

Comment: The second need some more major smartness to your code, as the closing node needs to "know" of its children and then recursively call some "close"-function on them. You would then probalby use javascript-object representation of all functionality for one "node" and then do that there. Are you planning on building this dynamically at some point?

Comment: Not really dynamic. For the foreseeable future, I plan to have just three - four stages. So I prefer keeping it static. As for creating the close function, I realised it'll be quite tricky but I just can't figure it out. I tried a lot of methods. I tried creating wrapper divs that had a different ID than the one that was open etc etc. Nothing worked. I think your solution makes sense. Need to figure out how to go about it

Comment: You could make a "clidren-graph" by an array though. I'll test and update my answer.

Comment: I should add the second part to the JS already present? And where should I call the function?

Comment: Hmm, seems like I've copy-pasted a bit too fast. The first four lines are the inner content of showdiv

Answer (score 1):

For part 2 I would again use the DOM to your advantage. I agree that if you intend to generate these dynamically it's going to take some rework of the DOM structure and code.

For this example however, I created the following JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/HRedA/15/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="stage-one">
        <div class="box node-one"></div>
        <div class="stage-two" id="two" style='display:none'>
            <div class="box node-two">
                <div class="stage-three-one" id="three-one" style="display:none;">
                    <div class="box node-four"></div>
                    <div class="box node-five"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box node-three">
                <div class="stage-three-two" id="three-two" style="display:none;">
                    <div class="box node-six"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

So the html above is reduced so it's not cluttering the page, but you'll notice that instead of all the elements being at the same level the nodes are structured inside of one another just like the flow diagram is structured. This means that when you hide a parent it will also hide it's children. This has the side-effect/feature of also remembering what you had expanded. For example if you hide the root and then show it again all your previous expansions will remain.

The reason this won't work dynamically is that all the lines and boxes are positioned by hand. I even had to move some around when they became children of other nodes.

Hope this helps.